# Image magnifier is not working using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, zooming

image magnifire not working:
i am setting product magnifier on image using jquery but working please help me i am new in development.
this is the url : http://thefashionista.in/single.php?p_id=8
error in cosole : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).picZoomer is not a function

Comment: Did you include the `picZoomer` library? It might help to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: yes here are these : <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-picZoomer.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-picZoomer.js"></script>
    <!-- image magnifire start-->

Comment: Two different versions of jQuery are loaded: `1.11.3` and `3.2.1`. That might be causing trouble. See [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: thanks this worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-picZoomer.js"></script>
```

You are trying to load the `picZoomer` from the `css` folder. Based on the docs on [Github](https://github.com/CodingSerf/jquery-picZoomer) the script should be loaded from the `src` folder

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery-picZoomer.js"></script>
```

Comment: True, but the [file seems to exist](http://thefashionista.in/css/jquery-picZoomer.js).